# Android - Removing the gray border of an imagebutton programmatically

Tags: android, imagebutton

I have an application that generates imageButtons and places them in a TableRow.

However, the imageButton has a gray border along the sides that weren't on the image in the drawable folder.

How can I programmatically remove these borders? So far, the solution I've seen use the xml properties in the layout but I can't use that solution since I programmatically generate my imageButtons.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer.

imageButton.setBackground(null);

Comment: i'm sorry! i didn't saw this answer!

Comment: It's okay, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imagebutton);
btn.setBackground(null);
```

Good luck